# python 3.2 global variable not updating when its in a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, while-loop, python-3.2

I'm making a program and I got into a problem.
I have a **thread** running which has a while loop that checks if a global variable is equal to False, if its equal to True then exit the while loop.
The problem is even if i update the global variable to True it still doesn't stop, it just continues on.

Code:

While loop:

```
while stopIt==False:
    print(stopIt) # Always prints out False, even when exit() is called
    # do things...
```

Stopper:

```
def exit():
    stopIt = True
```

stopIt variable defenition:

```
global stopIt
stopIt = False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `global` declaration must be inside the function where you modify the global variable:

```
def exit():
    global stopIt
    stopIt = True
```