# Global variable in thread class does not update

Tags: python

[A couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790570/python-global-variable-with-thread) of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742648/python-3-2-global-variable-not-updating-when-its-in-a-thread) on this, but I believe I'm already following their solutions.  In the following example, can anyone say why the thread doesn't find that `boolean` is updated to True?  I've defined it globally..

```
import threading
import time

boolean = False

class ThreadClass(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self):
    global boolean
    super(ThreadClass, self).__init__()
  def run(self):
    global boolean
    for i in range(6):
      print str(i)
      time.sleep(1)

t = ThreadClass().start()
time.sleep(3)
boolean = True
print 'end script'
0
1
2
end script
3
4
5
```

Comment: You are not looking at boolean in the thread... so how do you know it's not seeing it?

Comment: @jszakmeister, Beat me to it.  That question takes the cake.  It's equivalent to asking why `x = 10` and `print 'hello'` doesn't print 10.

Comment: Fair criticism. I have a different script that did look at the global, but I toyed it for the question without a sanity check..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `print str(i)` to `print str(i), boolean` and you'll see that it does change:

```
:: python so-python-thread.py
0 False
1 False
2 False
end script
3 True
4 True
5 True
```

Here's my version of the code:

```
import threading
import time


boolean = False


class ThreadClass(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ThreadClass, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        global boolean
        for i in range(6):
            print str(i), boolean
            time.sleep(1)


t = ThreadClass().start()
time.sleep(3)
boolean = True
print 'end script'
```

You actually have a small bug:

```
t = ThreadClass().start()
```

The `start()` method returns `None`, so `t` will be `None`.  You need to separately instantiate the thread, then start it.  Also, I'd explicitly wait for the thread to join:

```
import threading
import time


boolean = False


class ThreadClass(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ThreadClass, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        global boolean
        for i in range(6):
            print str(i), boolean
            time.sleep(1)


t = ThreadClass()
t.start()

time.sleep(3)
boolean = True

t.join()
print 'end script'
```